# How to match time pattern in Android

Tags: java, android

I have an edit text field in app where user can insert time manually. I want to match proper date pattern like `1:00 AM` - user can enter time in this format only if it's not in given format then it shows an error.

How can I make pattern matcher for this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the user input time in a proper data time format. then you can match with the user-given time date-time format what you want. like this

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm A",Locale.getDefault());
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();

Date date1 = dateFormat.parse(editText.getText().toString());
Date date2 = dateFormat.parse(calendar2.getTime());

if (date1.after(date2) && date1.equals(date2)) {
//..do your work..//
}
```

This is an example code. It may not work. I just put this to give you the idea what I am saying